# Puzzle game: Making one object switch places with another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onmousedown

I'm VERY new at programming in unity and it really is not my forte.
But I really need help with this.

I need help making a code that will change places with two game objects (8 in total all need to be able to switch with eachother) I want to use the mouse left key click to work.

All I got this far is:

`void OnMouseDown ()
{
   transform.position = otherObject.transform.position;
}`

but this doesn't do anything.. please help! :)

Answer (score 0):

For `OnMouseDown()` message to work you have to attach a `Collider` component. Go to `Component->Physics` menu and select a collider that fits your object. Most likely you want to use a `Box Collider`.

To switch objects you can do this:

```
void OnMouseDown ()
{
    Vector3 temp = transform.position;
    transform.position = otherObject.transform.position;
    otherObject.transform.position = temp;
}
```